# How to save a selection from Google Spreadsheet to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use Google Script to save a selected range from a spreadsheet and save it as a pdf in Google Drive.  I can save the entire spreadsheet (all 900 rows) with this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var blob = ss.getBlob().setName('report.pdf');
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("MOR598").next(); 
var file=DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

But since it's easy to manually select a range and download it as pdf, I would think you can do the same using script - but I haven't found any way to do this.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.  As far as I know, there is no way to duplicate, with code, what you can do manually with saving a range as a pdf.  One possible solution is to have a separate spreadsheet file as a template for the pdf, then write the data that you want to the template pdf, then save the template as a pdf.  I've had success with that strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sandy..after awhile I was able to find a way to simply delete all the rows at the bottom of the spreadsheet using this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
var max = ss.getActiveSheet();
var delRows=max.getMaxRows()-lastRow;
if (delRows>0){
  ss.deleteRows(lastRow+1, delRows);
}
```

While this won't help on specific selections, at least it got me where I wanted.